# Best way to handle continuous flow of small byte arrays that need to be flattened?

Tags: android, performance, bluetooth-lowenergy, kotlin-coroutines

I'm receiving a large batch of data from a BLE server via `NOTIFY`. On the iOS counterpart of the app, this transfer is pretty straightforward and has no performance drop, however on Android I can't seem to find an implementation that doesn't have terrible performance.

The initial implementation used a simple ByteArray override:

```kotlin
// Warning! Semi-pseudocode

var rawData = ByteArray(0)

characteristic.onReceive { data ->
    rawData += data
}
```

This works pretty okay up until around 3MB transferred. After that, the assignment slows down incredibly (e.g. first 10% - ~1MB - would transfer under a minute, second 10% would be around a minute, third 10% almost 2 minutes, then all the following batches increase in time by roughly the amount the previous batch took, think Fibonacci sequence). I understand this is because with every `onReceive` call, I create a new ByteArray and throw away the previous object, at the end resulting in GC collecting 2-3MB objects.

This is obviously not optimal, especially when the full transfer is ~16MB.

I've tried a preallocated `ByteBuffer` (both native and Java-based allocation), `LinkedList` and `Array` of ByteArrays, and so on.

The `onReceive` part is solved with Kotlin Coroutines (`ReceiveChannel<ByteArray>` and `Flow<ByteArray>`), and if I'm not saving the data, it is even faster than iOS (mainly due to the MTU difference - 162 vs 250 bytes received).

What would be the optimal way of collating these received batches into a single ByteArray?

Comment: What was the bad thing about the preallocated buffer? This typically works by resizing in exponential steps (size *= 1.5).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik apart from the steep decrease in speed, nothing really. When using a preallocated ByteBuffer, transfer speeds dropped to around what I was experiencing with the recreation of the ByteArray at every notification. So basically, say, with a ByteArray, the first MB took 1 minute, the fifth MB took ~6 minutes, with a ByteBuffer, the first MB would take ~6 minutes as well.

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense, if you really allocate just once at the beginning. If that performs poorly, the reason is not that you preallocated the buffer but something else you haven't brought up yet.

Comment: Another point: 1 MB in almost a minute translates to a meager 130 kbit/s, a solution must _really_ get it wrong to not be able to keep up with even that. Exponentially resizing the buffer adds just an O(1) per-byte overhead to a fully preallocated buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be confident your issue is related to buffer allocation, but we use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to aggregate MTU-sized segments coming from characteristic notifications.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream inputBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic chr) {
  inputBuffer.write(chr.getValue());
}
```